# Conda environment from linux to windows

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I am working on an image processing / computer vision / deep learning app which requires the use of old versions for some Python packages.
I am new to the world of machine learning and software,it's been 6 months that I made a career change and I am not aware of the best practices when it comes to python projects that work for different platforms (Windows, Linux, MacOS).
So today, I am working on a linux, I did some conda installs and some pip installs and I am exporting my environment to a .yml file. How to make sure that creating a virtual environment on a Windows Machine using conda and my exported .yml file is going to work with no problems ?

Comment: please mark an answer if it was useful. If an answer helped you please mark it as well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you create the virtual environment e.g.

```
pipenv shell
```

then you write a batch script checking for python packages in that environment:

```
echo %time% Check if python packages are installed...
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------
pip install -r [your .yml file]
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make sure your `.yml` file doesn't include platform dependent packages by adding the `--from-history` flag when creating the file. This exports only packages you intentionally installed.

On Windows `conda` will take care of the virtual environment by installing dependencies for the specified packages in the `.yml` file that are Windows compatible.